# can't export glad symbols across dll

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker-errors, extern

I am compiling a dynamic library using several objects, one of which is compiled with `glad.h/.c`. There are `extern` variables (gl function pointers) that I want to expose in case `gl_traits` library (object) is going to be compiled into some containing dll.

gl_traits.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef GL_TRAITS_BUILD
#define GLT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#define GLAD_GLAPI_EXPORT_BUILD
#else
#define GLT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define GLAD_GLAPI_EXPORT
#include "glad.h"
```

shader_traits.cpp

```
#define GL_TRAITS_BUILD
#include "gl_traits.h"
```

However, when I link to my containing dll and try to reference any exported (supposedly) gl function pointers (for example, `auto ptr = &glGenBuffers`, I get unresolved external symbols.

```
1>sandboxGL.cpp
1>sandboxGL.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glad_glGenBuffers
1>C:\dev_build\test_exportGLAD\sandboxDLL\bin\Debug\sandboxGL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I added another dummy Object (ObjectLib), that exports a function pointer, and it does just fine (*the function is being invoked correctly via extern pointer*).

ObjecLib.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define API __declspec(dllexport) extern
#else 
#define API __declspec(dllimport) extern
#endif // !BUILD_DLL


API int FromObject();

using PFuncInt = int(*)();

API PFuncInt ppObject;
```

ObjectLib.cpp

```
#define BUILD_DLL
#include "ObjectLib.h"

API int FromObject()
{
    return 16;
}


int Return48()
{
    return 1516;
}

PFuncInt ppObject = &Return48;
```

I am generating a project using CMake. 
`gl_traits` object (and similarly - ObjectLib):

```
add_library(gl_traits
    OBJECT
        include/gl_traits.h
        include/glad.h
        src/glad/glad.c

        src/shader_traits.cpp
    )

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenGL libs: ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}")

target_include_directories(gl_traits
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    )

target_link_libraries(gl_traits
    PRIVATE
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

Cmake file for building shared library that must contain among other objects `gl_traits`:

```
add_library(sandboxDLL
    SHARED
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:gl_traits>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ObjectLib>
    )

target_link_libraries(sandboxDLL
    PUBLIC
        gl_traits
        ObjectLib
    )

add_executable(sandboxGL
    sandboxGL.cpp
    )

target_link_libraries(sandboxGL
    PRIVATE
        sandboxDLL
    )
```

sandboxGL.cpp

```
#include "sbDLL.h"
#include "gl_traits.h"

#include "ObjectLib.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int a1 = a;

    auto ptr = &glGenBuffers;
    auto pptr = &exportedHello;

    //extern pointer from ObjectLib
    std::cout << ppObject() << std::endl;

    //extern function, defined in shader_traits.cpp
    exportedHello();

    return 0;
}
```

You can clone this project from git:
[HTTP](https://github.com/ElDesalmado/test_exportGLAD.git)
[SSH](http://git@github.com:ElDesalmado/test_exportGLAD.git)

What is the reason of a linker's failure to resolve symbols exported from glad?

---

**UPDATE**

If I compile `glad.h/.c` into separated shared library, using `target_compile_definitions(glad_obj PRIVATE GLAD_GLAPI_EXPORT GLAD_GLAPI_EXPORT_BUILD)`, everything links fine. But why not when compiling as Object?

**UPDATE2**

I've build `glad_obj` as an OBJECT, using `target_compile_definitions(glad_obj PRIVATE GLAD_GLAPI_EXPORT GLAD_GLAPI_EXPORT_BUILD)`. Then I build `gl_traits` also as an OBJECT and link it with `glad_obj`.
The next step is SHARED dll, that absorbs those 3 objects (including dummy ObjectLib), which is linked with final executable and everything works fine.

So, the unknown part is why linking fails when `#define GLAD_GLAPI_EXPORT_BUILD` macro is defined whilst explicitly adding the macro via cmake command doesn't?
Though currently this workaround is sufficient, I need `gl_traits` and `glad` to be one library.

Comment: Did you added `target_compile_definitions(gl_traits PRIVATE GL_TRAITS_BUILD)` and `target_compile_definitions(ObjectLib PRIVATE BUILD_DLL)` to your CMakeLists.txt? I did not see it in the fragments you provided.

Comment: @vre At first I did't. But after adding it didn't make any changes. Why should it?

Comment: @vre ObjectLib links fine without `target_compile_definitions`

Comment: I've missed that the symbols are defined in the cpp sources, So my comment does not apply.